# Composer [UnexpectedValueException] Your github oauth token for github.com contains invalid characters:

Tags: composer-php, token

Here i am.
I already try few answers in StackOverFlow to fix this issue but it didn't work for me and i don't know what else can i do...
So i want to install my project and every time i get this issue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk3vH.jpg)

- I went to the file auth.json
  `{"github-oauth": { "github.com": "ghp_uZfXyLME3qawVSyaZGRIhj3upFgaH24JYBn } }`

and i took of the  "github.com": "ghp_uZfXyLME3qawVSyaZGRIhj3upFgaH24JYBn"
to get

`{"github-oauth": { } }`

- I run composer self:update
- I put back the line with the token
- I try to install my app
- And i get the same issue...

If somebody has anyidea how to fix it ?

I'm working actually with composer 2.1.6

Answer (score 0):

This worked by using:

```
export COMPOSER_AUTH="{\"http-basic\": {\"github.com\": {\"username\":\"github_username\",\"password\":\"github_token\"}}}"
```

**Note:**
Replace (*[github_username](https://github.com/settings/admin)*/*[github_token](https://github.com/settings/tokens)*) by your own credentials